# Support for Python3/GTK+3 appindicators in Unity 8?

Tags: indicator, python3, gtk3, unity8

Using a live USB with Ubuntu 16.10 and the Unity 8 session, I tested a number of appindicators which I have developed in Python3/GTK+3/Unity7.

In short, they didn't exactly run and crashed in various ways.  Doing a Google search, I have not been able to determine if appindicators developed in Python3/GTK+3 will be supported in Unity 8.

I have asked on the IRC channels of #ubuntu-desktop and #ubuntu-unity but got no answer.  I have also sent an email to ubuntu-desktop@lists.ubuntu.com and got no answer.  So now trying AskUbuntu...

Does anyone have information on the supported platforms/library/languages for Unity 8 for appindicators please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is Unity is no [more](https://insights.ubuntu.com/2017/04/05/growing-ubuntu-for-cloud-and-iot-rather-than-phone-and-convergence).

Comment: Unity is here yunit.io